# How to make Typescript annotations mandatory for constants that are assigned function results?

Tags: typescript, coding-style, tslint, typescript-eslint

For this type of constants I want Typescript to infer the type:

```
const foo = 'foo';
```

And for the constants that are assigned a result of some function results I want annotations to be mandatory:

```
const bar: number = baz();
```

Is there TS compiler option or TSlint rule or smth?

Comment: can i ask why? functions should have their return type inferred just the same as variables; if they can't then i suggest turning on "noImplicitAny" which will flag this

Comment: for the sake that I can know what type this functions returns; not looking at function declaration, but on variable that is being assigned the result of func execution. Additionally, when writing code logic, I know for sure which type of constant I am currently declaring - but I can forget that the function I call can return a totally different type; or I can err. Anyway, I think that's unnec. mental burden which I'd like to be rid of. Thus I want to always declare types for constants that are assigned func. results.

Comment: depending on your editor you can just hold ctrl + hover over the function and it will normally tell you the return type (webstorm/vscode)

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about that :thumbsup: But I still want to enforce this is in my code. As far as I can tell the only solution is to write a custom eslint rule..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in TypeScript or the built-in [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io) lint rules. That's in large part because, as [@Shanon Jackson commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453944/how-to-make-typescript-annotations-mandatory-for-constants-that-are-assigned-fun#comment101382532_57453944), it's not generally best practice to write variable annotations unnecessarily.

The [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/typedef` lint rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef) can enforce type annotations in variables and/or other constructs. But it can't be configured to do what this question wants. Its docs also strongly recommend using TypeScript's `--noImplicitAny` and `--strictPropertyInitialization`.

If you *really* want to do this you could write a [custom rule with typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules). Or, for a bit less code, you could use [ESLint's `no-restricted-syntax` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) to ban *variable declarators* whose *id* doesn't have a *type annotation* and whose *initial value* is of type *call expression*:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      {
        "message": "My preference is type annotations on variables initialized to function call results",
        "selector": "VariableDeclarator:not([id.typeAnnotation])[init.type=CallExpression]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[typescript-eslint playground showing this banning the proposed variables as requested](https://typescript-eslint.io/play#ts=5.3.3&fileType=.tsx&esQuery=N4IgZglgNgLgpgJxALhANQIYIhgRlOAETgGMosMYB7BZAOypgAoBtCAEwDoYBPABzgBBOgxiUIVOgF0AlAAIQAGhABnOARLUkyULwEoQJKgFs%2BVAK512S1etJaVKFrv5wDHOHRgRIiGwDcMKHM3VExsPAJiMgotEABfRRd9VFEbNQ0HJ2TQkEoYbFxzeBs6DGNcjm5XYVFxSQSpeKb4oA&code=CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwCMoAvACgEoAueVZAWwJBgG4AoVsPAZw3ingC8hEhTadUPQtVoMmg4WXJsgA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQHYHsBaaFAF2gEsBjUxAE0OQE9dSBDAD3TAG1xsciaNHzRIAGn4CsA7JAC2KZGwDmibpACyTMAAcSAMyGJcVRGArIwpJrvNtcBdqQr5cVt2ABubSmwBGSFYUuBQubPAUAF701vhgBrCmLp5UEfBgJMgIpKiSsnLIiEg0ohoAar4UAUgAIohU8L5spKJoTgAUPBR0AHQ2dgCCjvjOrrgAugCU3aGk-baIALwAwukAohz6SuMTkFLYAL4HE-zHh0A&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false)